# PHP 7 подключить библиотеку загруженную composer require

Tags: composer, php7, есиа

Установил библиотеку командой

```
composer require ekapusta/oauth2-esia
```

В папке проекта появилась папка **vendor** с кучей зависимостей, необходимых, как я понимаю, *[oauth2-esia](https://github.com/ekapusta/oauth2-esia)*, и файл *autoload.php*.

Подозреваю, что теперь как-то нужно подключить библиотеку в *index.php*, лежащим в корне проекта.

Но я, хоть убей, не могу понять как это сделать?
Подскажите, как достучаться до класса *EsiaProvider* объявленного в библиотеке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

файл autoload вам нужно подключить при инициализации системы. Увы не могу точно сказать где, потому как вы не пишите с чем работаете - фреймворк/что-то самописное и т.д.

```
require_once "path/to/vendor/autoload.php";
```

Далее на странице, где вы хотите достучаться до нужно либы используете

```
use Ekapusta\OAuth2Esia\Provider\EsiaProvider;
use Ekapusta\OAuth2Esia\Security\Signer\OpensslPkcs7;
```

пример я взял из доков в гите и далее уже работаете непосредственно с классом.

Если композер с либами нужно подключить только в одном месте то используйте вышеописанное прямо на странице/в контроллере/модуле/etc

```
require_once "path/to/vendor/autoload.php";
use Ekapusta\OAuth2Esia\Provider\EsiaProvider;
use Ekapusta\OAuth2Esia\Security\Signer\OpensslPkcs7;
```

Подробнее об использовании композера вы можете прочитать на [официальном сайте](https://getcomposer.org/doc/) или в [статье на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/112640/)